# How to test placeholder text on input field in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

We're adding some translations to our applications and I need to make a few protractor tests that grab placeholder text and check that it's being properly loaded.

How do I check the text of the placeholder on an input field using protractor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Protractor FAQ](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#the-result-of-gettext-from-an-input-element-is-always-empty), try `element.getAttribute('value')`

Answer (score 2):

```
element(by.model('<modelName>')).getAttribute('placeholder').then(function(element){
    expect(element).toEqual('<expected placeholder txt>');
});
```

This works for me. I used it with `model`, you can use it with any element you are testing.